# How to see again the errors when booting?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, pop-os

I see some errors when booting

```
[ FAILED ] bla bla
[ FAILED ] bla bla
```

but it goes too fast before directly goes to GUI, how to see those messages back?
I've tried `journalctl -r` or `dmesg -w` it doesn't show something like that. ctrl+alt+F1/F2 also already became GUI, ctrl+alt+F3 to F6 also just normal tty login prompt, so can't see those anymore.

So how to see again those booting errors?

I'm using PopOS 22.04 (Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 4):

Debian 11 seems to have `/var/log/boot.log` (and its logrotated older versions `boot.log.1`, `boot.log.2` etc.). It would seem to contain the sort of messages you're looking for.

Perhaps Ubuntu has it too?

Example:

```
------------ <timestamp redacted> ------------
done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.

Welcome to Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)!

[  OK  ] Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-openvpn.slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-postfix.slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice User and Session Slice.
[  OK  ] Started Forward Password R…uests to Wall Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Set up automount Arbitrary…s File System Automount Point.
[  OK  ] Reached target Slices.
```

... and so on, with colours and bold effect if you view it using `less -R boot.log`.

Comment: ah too bad, I only see on `/var/log/boot.log.1` but it was last years', the `/var/log/boot.log` is empty, maybe they removed it on 22.04 update (I'm using PopOS actually)